# Is $NC_1$ vs PP still an open problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Is $NC_1$ vs PP still an open problem?
I done a few searched but I can't find an answer.

Comment: PP is contained in PSPACE. We can't separate NC$^1$ from PSPACE.

Comment: Isn’t $NC_1$ contained in Logspace which is strictly contained in PSPACE?

Comment: You might have a point...

Comment: The only proof techniques we currently have is hierarchy theorems (which separate L from PSPACE), combinatorial techniques (which give lower bounds against circuits with depth up to roughly $\log n/\log\log n$), and diagonalization (Ryan Williams' method), which is useful for classes such as ACC.

Comment: Apparently PP can be separated from TC$^0$, but I doubt we can separate NC$^1$ from PP.

Comment: As I have seen on wikipedia, $PH\subseteq P^{PP}$ and $NC_1\subseteq P$, so if $NC_1=PP$ the entire polynomial time hierarchy would have collapsed to $P$ (also resulting in $P=NP$)